# How can I get the first occurrence of a user in a series, by the last user in a stream?

Tags: rethinkdb

Consider the following stream (indexed by timestamp):

```
[
  { name: "John",   timestamp: 1 },
  { name: "George", timestamp: 2 }, // George's first occurrence in stream but not 'in a series'
  { name: "Ringo",  timestamp: 3 },
  { name: "Paul",   timestamp: 4 },
  { name: "George", timestamp: 5 }, // Bingo!
  { name: "George", timestamp: 6 },
  { name: "George", timestamp: 7 }
]
```

George is the last user, so this is the user who I'm interested in, and his first appearance in a row (in a 'series'?) is 5: `{ name: "George", timestamp: 5 }`

How can I get this doc with rql?

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a good way to do this in ReQL right now, but here's what I'd do:

```
r.table('test').filter({name: 'George'}).coerceTo('array').do(function(arr) {
  return r.concatMap(arr, arr.skip(1), function(cur, next) {
    return r.branch(cur('timestamp').eq(next('timestamp')), [cur], [])
  })(0);
});
```

Comment: Doesn't coerceTo('array') mean converting all rows to an n size array at all times..? If so it looks very expansive :/

Comment: Yeah, it is.  I can't think of a less-expensive way with the current set of ReQL terms, but maybe one exists.